# Efficient algorithm for iterative ranking of a vector

Tags: fortran, ranking

Suppose I've a scrambled vector of consecutive integers 1:n, say {3,6,2,1,4,5}. My problem is to find, for each element, the number of elements to its left that are smaller than itself. So I'd like the program to return {0,1,0,0,3,4} for this example. This is what I've written in Fortran:

```
subroutine iterrank(n,invec,outvec,tempvec)
    implicit none

    integer :: n, i, currank
    integer, dimension(n) :: invec, outvec, tempvec

    tempvec = 0
    outvec = 0
    do i = 1,n
        currank = invec(i)
        outvec(i) = tempvec(currank)
        tempvec(currank:n) = tempvec(currank:n) + 1
    end do

    return
end subroutine
```

It takes a temporary array (vector), and for each digit *d* the loop comes across, it adds 1 to every element beyond position *d* in the temporary vector. The next iteration then takes the appropriate element in the temporary vector as the count of elements smaller than itself. My questions are:

1) I believe this is of complexity O(n^2), since there are O(n) writes to the temporary vector in each iteration of the loop. Am I correct?

2) Is there a more efficient way of doing this for large n (say, >100k)?

Comment: As this isn't a programming problem, it may be that your question is better suited to [cs.se].

Comment: Your subroutine does not give the predicted results on your test data. I just ran it. It is giving the predicted result plus 1 for each element of the output array?

Comment: @innoSPG thanks for pointing that out. I've removed the line that added the extra 1 (it was needed for my intended purpose, but irrelevant to the question asked).

Comment: @francescalus I don't really know if it's more about programming or CS, since good programming could indeed lead to huge time savings while a better algorithm altogether may achieve the same purpose. Anyway I've reposted the question at http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/51460/efficient-algorithm-for-iterative-ranking-of-a-vector.

Comment: Yes, I didn't want to suggest it was off topic here, even when considering the algorithm rather than the Fortran.  I suspect one can do this as O(n*log n), but the CS people can do much better than my guess most likely.

Comment: @francescalus, for the future if you are going to suggest another site, please remind users not to cross-post their question on multiple Stack Exchange sites: that's prohibited by site rules, and we don't want to give them a bad experience by suggesting they do something that will just get closed for violating Stack Exchange rules.  You can let them know how to migrate their question if they think it'd be better-suited elsewhere.  Thank you!

Comment: @D.W. Fair points, but (in danger of going off-topic here), would it be easier to have something in the help section on CS we can point to along the lines of "It's been suggested on SO I ask my question here ..."?  If it comes to having that or a long comment as I had above appending "and to do that, flag for migration/delete here first, but don't forget to check for yourself it's on topic and that it hasn't been asked before..." (and countless other rules) I know which I'd prefer.

Comment: @francescalus, thanks for the suggestion.  Can I encourage you to post your helpful suggestion on [Meta.CS.SE]? That might be the best place for it to receive more attention and discussion.  I have two immediate reactions: (1) there's limited space available in the help page on what's on-topic, so we'd have to check if there's room to add anything more to that page -- but maybe we could add a new page to the help center?; (2) FYI, [the policy regarding cross-posting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/160917) isn't specific to CS or SO; it applies to the entire Stack Exchange network.

Comment: @D.W. Will do, or possibly even on Meta as as you say it's a non-specific problem.  It will be at least tomorrow, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this would be more efficient, and you could also reduce the temporary integer array to a single byte.

```
subroutine iterrank(n,invec,outvec,tempvec)
    implicit none

    integer :: n, i, currank
    integer, dimension(n) :: invec, outvec, tempvec

    tempvec = 0
    !outvec = 0 ! no need to initialize something overwritten below
    do i = 1 , n
        currank = invec(i)
        outvec(i) = sum( tempvec(1:currank) )
        tempvec(currank) = 1
    end do

end subroutine
```

The gain is that you are only writing twice per index, however you are reading elements a maximum of `n*n` times.

EDIT:

I haven't tried this, but it should do less reads, with a possible overhead of branching. It is possibly faster for extremely large arrays, I would however expect it to be slower for short arrays:

```
subroutine iterrank(n,invec,outvec,tempvec)
  implicit none

  integer :: n, i, currank, prevrank
  integer, dimension(n) :: invec, outvec, tempvec

  tempvec = 0
  outvec(1) = 0
  tempvec(invec(1)) = 1
  do i = 2 , n
     prevrank = invec(i-1)
     currank = invec(i)
     if ( abs(prevrank-currank) > currank ) then
        outvec(i) = sum( tempvec(1:currank) )
     else if ( prevrank < currank ) then
        outvec(i) = outvec(i-1) + sum( tempvec(prevrank:currank) )
     else
        outvec(i) = outvec(i-1) - sum( tempvec(currank:prevrank-1) )
     end if
     tempvec(currank) = 1
  end do

end subroutine iterrank
```

Comment: Thanks. It looks to be still O(n^2) but is noticeably faster when include it in R (for n=80k my code took ~7.8s, while your code took ~5.9s). However I've no clue as to why it is faster.. since the combined number of reads and writes appears to be the same as my code.

Comment: Please decipher how many read and writes there are in your code, opposed to my code. This should clarify where the difference comes from.

Comment: @David, hint, there _is_ a difference ;)

Comment: @David you could try the edit which perhaps is slightly faster, however, it is more dependent on input and fluctuations in speed may occur.

Comment: @zeroth, your new suggestion looks great, but it seems to not be producing the right result. Did you compare the result with the result of your original suggestion? I had similar idea, but to implement it I finally added another temporary vector.

Comment: @zeroth, especially, I end up having negative entry in `outvec` when using `outvec(i) = outvec(i-1) - sum( tempvec(currank:prevrank-1) )`. It is possibly the case in your suggestion too.

Comment: I have not tried it because I have no function to generate the data... I have only tried on a 10 element case (which works). However, there is one error which is now corrected.

Comment: @zeroth you can adapt a generator from this link http://computer-programming-forum.com/49-fortran/6484950822ad11d4.htm. It is a C code, but you do not need to understand the C language to translate it to fortran. Just for the confirmation, I tried the last version and I am it is producing the same result as the initial version on my 100k elements. I voted up the solution.

Comment: So did it work? I have just tested with the algorithm you provided, your implementation and mine yield the same result.

Comment: @David have you tried this? I think it is the fastest of the versions currently posted.

Comment: @zeroth I compared the code again - my original code did involve many more writes. I don't know, however, how the "sum" operation would factor in the time calculation. Your edited code provided even better time savings (roughly by half), thanks! It took me some time to understand how it works; I can see that you're trying to minimize reads by the splitting.

Answer (score 2):

Complete rewrite of the answer. If the memory is not a concern, you can add another vector and use an algorithm like the one bellow. The additional vector is used to compute the permutation. Thanks to the fact that the original vector is a permutation of integer 1 to n, the permutation is computed in O(n). with vectors of size 100k on my computer, this algorithm runs in 1.9 sec in average (100 runs) and the initial proposition of zeroth is 2.8 sec in average. I suggested this solution simply because zeroth said he did not test his new solution, you will test and use the best one.

```
subroutine iterrank(n,invec,outvec,tempvec,ord)
    implicit none
    !
    integer :: n, i, currPos, prevPos, currOut, prevOut
    integer, dimension(n) :: invec, outvec, tempvec,ord
    !
    tempvec = 0
    do i = 1, n
        ord(invec(i)) = i
    end do
    !
    currPos = ord(1)
    tempvec(currPos) = 1
    currOut = 0
    outvec(currPos) = currOut
    ! last = 0
    do i = 2 , n
        prevPos = currPos
        currPos = ord(i)
        !
        if(currPos>prevPos)then
            currOut = currOut+sum( tempvec(prevPos:currPos) )
        else
            currOut = sum( tempvec(1:currPos) )
        end if
        !
        outvec(currPos) = currOut
        tempvec(currPos) = 1
    end do
    !
end subroutine iterrank
```

The down side of this solution is the random access to vectors `outvec` and `tempvec`, that does not make the best use of cache and registers. It is possible to solve that and reduce significantly the time, possibly at the expense of additional temporary vectors.

Comment: Thanks - I've reposted the question at http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/51460/efficient-algorithm-for-iterative-ranking-of-a-vector. However your code here is much slower than the original code (~15s compared to ~7.8s for n=80k). I tried to avoid logical test since it appears to be a slower operation - please correct if I'm wrong.

Comment: @David, I did not time it and as analyse it, yes it can be slower than the original version. I will have a look at the new question.

Comment: @David, I rewrote the solution and it is faster the original solution of zeroth that was already genius. He has suggested a new one that also look awesome but seems to not work yet. If he correct it, it might be the best.

Comment: Thanks for the update - it's now faster but yes zeroth's edited one is even so. I've compared each piece of code with some randomly generated n=100k sets and each time they give identical rankings, and so I believe they're all working as they should now. If only I could accept both answers!